# Jquery UI Autocomplete from Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, json, autocomplete

I am trying to use jquerys autocomplete with my database but I can't figure out how to return the data from my php script as options for the autocomplete.

Here is what I have at the moment based on another forum post:

```
$('input#transferto').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response)
                {
                    alert('{"term": "'+request.term+'", "mode": "ENTITY_AUTOCOMPLETE"}');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: SYSTEM_ROOT+'/assets/controllers/global.php',
                        data: 'dataString={"term": "'+request.term+'", "mode": "ENTITY_AUTOCOMPLETE"}',
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            //alert(data);
                            //data = $.parseJSON(data) ;
                            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                return{
                                    label: item.user_login_name,
                                    value: item.user_id
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
                minLength: 3,
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: false,
                delay: 500,
```

And in my php file:

```
if($mode == 'ENTITY_AUTOCOMPLETE')
{
    $query = trim(strip_tags($JSON->term));
    $q = $query.'%' ;
    $result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM entity_details WHERE name LIKE ?") ;
    $result->execute(array($q)) ;

    //$data = '{' ;
    //while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //foreach($row as $key => $val)
            //$data .= '"'.$key.'": "'.rawurldecode($val).'", ' ;
    //}
    //$data = substr($data, 0, strlen($data)-2).'}' ;
    $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;
    echo print_r($data) ;
}
```

As you can see I have tried returning just an array and tried JSON but to no avail.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

`url: SYSTEM_ROOT+'/assets/controllers/global.php',`

1) What's SYSTEM_ROOT root? You don't have this defined anywhere.

`data: 'dataString={"term": "'+request.term+'", "mode": "ENTITY_AUTOCOMPLETE"}',`

2) The way your passing your data string is unnecessary. As the jquery docs specify, this is converted to a query string, if not already a string and appended to the url for GET-requests. If you use an object it must be a key/value pairs. Meanwhile you're trying to stuff an object inside a querystring as a string.

`if($mode == 'ENTITY_AUTOCOMPLETE')`

3) On this line your accessing `$mode` which is not defined/declared. Normally with a GET request you would check with `$_GET['mode']` but in your case it won't be in there because you've messed up the data your passing (mentioned in 2)

**Open up NET panel and also check your console for errors to debug.**